# How can we find UIWebView in Project and replace it with WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, app-store, wkwebview

We got this email from no_reply@email.apple.com while uploading a build:

> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App Name" 1.0 (5.0). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

I've not used UIWebView in my project. I've updated all pods. I searched word 'UIWebView' in the workspace, but nothing was found. I also searched in the terminal using `grep -r -f "UIWebView".`, getting `grep: UIWebView.: No such file or directory`.

What should I do before uploading a new build?

Comment: Do what they said use WKWebView instead of UIWebView

Comment: Yes, But I've never used UIWebView in my project.

Comment: In this case reply to them

Comment: Getting email from no_reply@email.apple.com.

Comment: there is an option to reply in your AppStore account where you see your app builds if they are approved or not

Comment: Where exactly ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: AppStoreComnect MyApps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212971/discussion-between-akshay-phulare-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: check your libraries you are using ....whether they use uiwebview

Comment: This is for firebase.Just update pod

Comment: My all pods are updated, but still getting the same warning email. There is no `UIWebView` in my project. I searched by terminal. What should I do now? Any suggestion please?

Comment: @Tulon Check Answer and search in project as mentioned in step no.3.

Comment: @AkshayPhulare I have searched by `grep -r "UIWebView" .` and there is no
 `UIWebview` in my project. But Facebook, Twitter & Google SDK used the instance name for `WKWebView` as `webview`. I don't think apple is not smart enough to detect that right? So literally there is no `UIWebView` in my project. But still, apple rejecting my build. Feeling helpless. :(

Comment: @Tulon I faced same situation few day ago. I got many rejections and suddenly Apple accepts my build. Now try your luck.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved a similar problem as follows:

1. Search in the workspace UIWebView and replace it with WKWebView
2. Remove UIWebView in the storyboards and add "WKWebView" instead (do not forget about the connection with the code)
3. In the terminal, in the project folder, enter the command:

   `grep -r "UIWebView" .`

   (don't forget the space and the dot at the end of command!) to find links to UIWebView in library files.
4. Update the libraries with UIWebView, and if it does not help, then delete all libraries that have links to UIWebView.
   (Most libraries with UIWebView have new updates without UIWebView.)

Comment: step 3 for Binary files 

Comment: Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'WKWebView', error after replacing UIWebView in React.xcodeproj

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just went `grep -r "UIWebView" .`, changed UIWebview to WKWebview, and updated pods that used UIWebview to the newer versions I found.

FBSDK at version 5.5 worked.