# AppStore keeps rejecting my build due to having UIWebView even though I removed all usage

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, app-store

Apple has stopped accepting new apps with UIWebView, my app had some usage and was removed then I updated the FB sdk and it was removed there yet my build is getting rejected,

Contacted apple support they guided me to `grep -R UIWebView *` on the **xcarchive**
when I run the command I get the following result which is confusing to me, how to remove UIWebView from DSYM files or what is the correct course of action please

```
BCSymbolMaps/12DE5FB2-2DBE-3A66-ABD5-2B64CE66D422.bcsymbolmap:l_OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_UIWebViewDelegate
BCSymbolMaps/12DE5FB2-2DBE-3A66-ABD5-2B64CE66D422.bcsymbolmap:l_OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_UIWebViewDelegate
Binary file Products/Applications/APPNAME.app/APPNAME matches
Binary file dSYMs/GTMSessionFetcher.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GTMSessionFetcher matches
Binary file dSYMs/Mixpanel.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Mixpanel matches
Binary file dSYMs/Lottie.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Lottie matches
Binary file dSYMs/Protobuf.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Protobuf matches
Binary file dSYMs/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GoogleToolboxForMac matches
Binary file dSYMs/RangeSeekSlider.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/RangeSeekSlider matches
Binary file dSYMs/PromiseKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/PromiseKit matches
Binary file dSYMs/SwiftyJSON.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SwiftyJSON matches
Binary file dSYMs/ADCountryPicker.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/ADCountryPicker matches
Binary file dSYMs/Toast_Swift.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Toast_Swift matches
Binary file dSYMs/SnapKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SnapKit matches
Binary file dSYMs/YoutubeKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/YoutubeKit matches
Binary file dSYMs/IGListKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/IGListKit matches
Binary file dSYMs/GoogleUtilities.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GoogleUtilities matches
Binary file dSYMs/AWSCore.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/AWSCore matches
Binary file dSYMs/AWSS3.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/AWSS3 matches
Binary file dSYMs/SocketRocket.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SocketRocket matches
Binary file dSYMs/TagListView.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/TagListView matches
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replaced UIWebView with WKWebView, but still same error from Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61575655/replaced-uiwebview-with-wkwebview-but-still-same-error-from-apple)

Comment: @SPatel No still I have the DSYM files of the pods how to remove them, when I search for UIWebView in my project there is no results

Comment: Can you try to alias UIWebView to WKWebView to see if compiler or linker can find some problem (typealias UIWebView = WKWebView)

Comment: Did you check [this issue on facebook site](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1993)

Comment: Also try to clean your build dir and check that you have not an old file in the project.

Comment: @PtitXav I have tried all suggestions nothing useful, the typealias line successfully builded an there was no issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep search into pods turns out googleSignin needed to be updated the issue was Google didn't clarify at which version they dropped UIWebKit